# Deleting the second element in tuples

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a list of tuples that look like this.

```
[ [(1,True),(2,True)] , [(3,False),(4,False),(5,False)] ]
```

My goal is so get `[1,2,3,4,5]` of out that mess.

I tried to use `map` and `filter` to remove all the `Bool`s but `filter` also removed the first element in the tuple. If I can remove the `Bool`s in each tuple then I can maybe use a loop to assign `fst` of each tuple to a new empty list?

Comment: Not quite sure what you meant by your last edit (that I rolled back)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
f :: [[(a, b)]] -> [a]
f = concatMap (map fst)
```

Then `f [ [(1,True),(2,True)] , [(3,False),(4,False),(5,False)] ]` is `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: wow that was a ridiculously easy solution. didn't know that you can apply fst to map. thanks!

Comment: You can give `map` **any function** and it will give you back a function that works on lists of the appropriate type.

Answer (score 4):

Or with list comprehensions:

```
f xss = [fst x | xs <- xss, x <- xs]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (edited, thanks to **Michael Kohl**'s and **pat**'s comments):

```
fun :: [[(a,b)]] -> [a]
fun = map fst . concat
```

Then in GHC:

```
*Main> let l = [ [(1,True),(2,True)] , [(3,False),(4,False),(5,False)] ]
[[(1,True),(2,True)],[(3,False),(4,False),(5,False)]]
*Main> fun l
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Your anonymous function is in the `Prelude` as `fst`: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:fst

Comment: Oh, then you also might want to look into `concatMap` instead of `map foo $ concat`.

Comment: First, it should be `fun = map fst . concat`, and second, `concatMap foo` is `concat . map foo` not `map foo . concat`

Comment: My bad, really. I thought I tried this function in GHC, but it really seems to be wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
foldl1 (\acc x -> acc ++ x)  [a | b <- lst, let a =  map fst b]
```